# NSLayoutConstraint IBOutlet does not respond to setActive:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, constraints

I have a `UIViewController` and I want to dynamically modify some of its layout according to, say, the click of a button.

As a simplified example, let's say I have created `UIView` in IB (self.box). In IB, set a constraint that makes the view's width equal to 0.9 of the VC's view's width.

Then I programmatically add another constraint and save it as a strong property. It sets the view's width to 0.7 of the VC's view's width, and I remove the previous constraint.

This leads to conflicting constraint errors and to a completely broken view. Whether I add or remove first or use the `.active` property instead of adding / removing, the same happens.

Any idea on how to make this work? My actual case is more complicated, but I have checked and only modifying a view's width constraint in my `UIViewController` leads to the error, even though setting it to different multipliers in IB does not lead to any conflicts.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    NSLayoutConstraint* lowWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.box attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.7 constant:0.f];
    self.lowWidth = lowWidth;

    [self.view removeConstraint:self.highWidth];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.lowWidth];
}
```

The constraint conflict includes the following:

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this:
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x145efb0f0 UIView:0x145d8d330.width == 0.7*UIView:0x14755e890.width>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1474589b0 UIView:0x145d8d330.width == 0.9*UIView:0x14755e890.width>
```

**EDIT**: calling setActive: on my IBOutlet constraint did not seem to work, so I removed the outlet and programmatically created the constraint instead. This time it works as intended, but I have no explanation as to why the outlet did not work. Note that setting to weak / strong does not change anything.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *highWidth;
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` or `[self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];`

Comment: You can ctrl-drag constraints from the storyboard to your view controller, rather than create them programatically. You can manipulate the IBOutlets for the constraints programatically. Have you tried that?

Comment: You still have given no real detail as to what you're doing. I'm kind of fed up, but before I go: Here's an example where I swap a bunch of constraints in and out in response to rotation. Sorry it's in Swift but the basics should be clear. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch01p041constraintSwapping2/ConstraintSwapping/ViewController.swift

Comment: Gosh matt, you're a real pal aren't you? There's no necessity to give more "detail" than that. I say everything that's required to know to understand the issue. And your example is interesting as it uses different views to avoid constraint conflicts. This doesn't respond to my IBOutlet issue though, but thanks for your time. Your passive-aggressiveness is an absolute pain, though, but then this is Stack, right?

Comment: Adrian B: that is precisely the issue, it appears. I controlled drag the "highWidth" constraint (built in IB) into my .m UIViewController file (see my question at the bottom). Then I tried to set this highWidth constraint to active = NO, but absolutely nothing happens. I then removed this IBOutlet and created the constraint programmatically instead, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use only one `NSLayoutConstraint` and modifying that constraint size.

```
self.highWidth?.contant = size
[self.view layoutIfNeeded]
```

or activating/deactivting constraints... [NSLayoutConstraint class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/)